# Cannot make Active Directory offline connection persistent

Tags: samba, authentication, active-directory, kerberos

After several weeks of tries and failure, I finally need to ask for help.

For starters, I use Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, that I have setup with winbind, PAM, Kerberos.

Overall, I am trying to make a workstation be able to use Active Directory accounts.
So far, I could manage the following :

- Join the machine to the Active Directory,
- Connect and use the accounts from Active Directory
- Today I even succeeded in making offline connection
  But the matter where I am extremely confused is about making offline connections after reboot.
  Considering the machine is a laptop, it will happen that it will be used outside any network connection, so I need it to work in this use case.

To explain more in details, and if I am not mistaken, the authentication token is cached in a krb5cc file, and it is this file I should preserve to allow offline authentication.

I think that a part of the problem is that the file is stored by default in /tmp.
As long as the machine is not rebooted, the file persists, so I can continue to authenticate.
I tried relocating the krb5cc file to /var/tmp since it was not purged upon reboot, but even if at some point I succeeded, it looks like the file was deleting after the AD user logged out. Not to mention that the parameter to change that location is available at 3 places (pam_winbind.conf, common-auth in pam_krb5.so and pam_winbind.so section), and I just can't figure out which one takes precedence.

Finally, I am not sure what's going on between the applications that should be involved in the authentication process (like pam, samba, winbind, kerberos), and the ones not involved but having an effect (apparmor, systemd tmpfiles.d)

I also tried to enable the logs trying to get more details to no avail.

Basically, I'd be happy to have a winning strategy like what place should I put the file in, and which place should I configure that.

Tried a whole bunch of documentation and configuration change, and I could not really get somewhere. Any pointer would be appreciated.

```
#
# /etc/pam.d/common-auth - authentication settings common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of the authentication modules that define
# the central authentication scheme for use on the system
# (e.g., /etc/shadow, LDAP, Kerberos, etc.).  The default is to use the
# traditional Unix authentication mechanisms.
#
# As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
# To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
# local modules either before or after the default block, and use
# pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
# pam-auth-update(8) for details.

# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    [success=4 default=ignore]  pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000 ccache=~/krb5commonauth_%u
auth    [success=3 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_winbind.so krb5_auth krb5_ccache_type=FILE:~/krb5cocommonauth_%u cached_login try_first_pass
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_sss.so use_first_pass
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required            pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
auth    optional pam_intune.so 
auth    optional            pam_cap.so 
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

```
#
# pam_winbind configuration file
#
# /etc/security/pam_winbind.conf
#
# For more details see man pam_winbind.conf(5)

[global]

# turn on debugging
;debug = no

# turn on extended PAM state debugging
;debug_state = no

# request a cached login if possible
# (needs "winbind offline logon = yes" in smb.conf)
cached_login = yes

# authenticate using kerberos
krb5_auth = yes

# when using kerberos, request a "FILE" or "DIR" krb5 credential cache type
# (leave empty to just do krb5 authentication but not have a ticket
# afterwards)
krb5_ccache_type = FILE:~/krbpwc_%u
;krb5_ccache_type = DIR:/run/user/%u/krb5cc

# make successful authentication dependend on membership of one SID
# (can also take a name)
;require_membership_of =

# password expiry warning period in days
;warn_pwd_expire = 14

# omit pam conversations
;silent = no
silent = no

# create homedirectory on the fly
;mkhomedir = no
mkhomedir = yes
```

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm = AP.ECOMM.GLOBAL

# The following krb5.conf variables are only for MIT Kerberos.
    kdc_timesync = 1
    ccache_type = 4
    forwardable = true
    proxiable = true
    default_ccache_name = FILE:/var/tmp/krb5cc_%{uid}

# The following encryption type specification will be used by MIT Kerberos
# if uncommented.  In general, the defaults in the MIT Kerberos code are
# correct and overriding these specifications only serves to disable new
# encryption types as they are added, creating interoperability problems.
#
# The only time when you might need to uncomment these lines and change
# the enctypes is if you have local software that will break on ticket
# caches containing ticket encryption types it doesn't know about (such as
# old versions of Sun Java).

#   default_tgs_enctypes = des3-hmac-sha1
#   default_tkt_enctypes = des3-hmac-sha1
#   permitted_enctypes = des3-hmac-sha1

# The following libdefaults parameters are only for Heimdal Kerberos.
    fcc-mit-ticketflags = true
    udp_preference_limit = 0

[logging]
    default = FILE:/var/tmp/krb5libs.log
    kdc = FILE:/var/tmp/krb5kdc.log
    admin_server = FILE:/var/tmp/kadmind.log

[realms]
    AP.ECOMM.GLOBAL = {
        kdc = 10.19.26.134
        admin_server = 10.19.26.134
    }
    ECOMM.GLOBAL = {
        kdc = 10.19.26.144
        admin_server = 10.19.26.144
        default_domain = ecomm.global
    }
[domain_realm]
    .ap.ecomm.global = AP.ECOMM.GLOBAL
    ap.ecomm.global = AP.ECOMM.GLOBAL
    .ecomm.global = ECOMM.GLOBAL
    ecomm.global = ECOMM.GLOBAL
```

A fun example looking for the ccache in /var/tmp, when it is located in /tmp.

```
dentsulinuxops@vn-7yndkr3:/var/log/samba$ klist
klist: No credentials cache found (filename: /var/tmp/krb5cc_1000)
dentsulinuxops@vn-7yndkr3:/var/log/samba$ ls -al /tmp
total 235
drwxrwxrwt 20 root     root           27 Thg 11 30 19:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 root     root           25 Thg 11 21 17:41 ..
drwxrwxrwt  2 root     root            2 Thg 11 30 18:00 .font-unix
drwxrwxrwt  2 root     root            6 Thg 11 30 18:02 .ICE-unix
-rw-------  1 olimaq   domain users 3737 Thg 11 30 19:01 krb5cc_170209_7UiwN1
srwxr-xr-x  1 root     root            0 Thg 11 30 18:00 nmh_msg_bus.sock
-rw-r--r--  1 root     mdatp          51 Thg 11 30 18:00 .ses
```

Comment: Update, the right place to configure the location for the ccache file is in the common-auth file.
That said, when the user logs out (without reboot) the krb5cc file disappear.
Not sure which process is involved or how to make that file persistent...